# Read Text from RTF file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I tried to read rtf file using Apache POI but I found issues with it. It reports Invalid Header exception. It seems like POI doesn't support rtf files. Is there any way to read .rtf using any **open source java API**. (I heard about Aspose API but it's not free)

Any solutions??

Comment: What do you want to extract from the RTF file? RTF is pretty simple, i'm sure you don't need a proprietary solution for that.

Comment: @remi benoit I just want to get plain text from the .rtf file

Comment: You could try JRTF. Works like a charm!!!

Answer (score 6):

You can try the [RTFEditorKit](http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html). It supports images and text as well.

Or look at this answer: [Java API to convert RTF file to Word document (97-2003 format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845453/java-api-to-convert-rtf-file-to-word-document-97-2003-format)

There is no free library that supports this. But it may not be that hard to create a basic compare function yourself. You can read in an rtf file and then extract the text like this:

```
// read rtf from file
JEditorPane p = new JEditorPane();
p.setContentType("text/rtf");
EditorKit rtfKit = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/rtf");
rtfKit.read(new FileReader(fileName), p.getDocument(), 0);
rtfKit = null;

// convert to text
EditorKit txtKit = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/plain");
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
txtKit.write(writer, p.getDocument(), 0, p.getDocument().getLength());
String documentText = writer.toString();
```

Comment: Isn't that a commercial one?. That's what the link says. I said "Open source java API " with  bold letters in my post. If i am not wrong , what you suggested is not an API first of all.